# Writing data to excel iteratively

Tags: python, xlwt

I have 2 lists and below is what i wanna do:
b = ['ibm cloud','dell cloud']
a =['wen','see','there']

I want to create 2 different worksheets with the list items in b. and then write to the worksheets the list items from a in the rows. And i am unable to do so.

`import xlwt
base = xlwt.Workbook()
for a in a:
    sheet = base.add_sheet(a)
    for b in b:
        sheet.write(row,col,b)`

Please help

Comment: In what pattern you want to write the rows/columns with values from `b`?

Comment: As of now i just want to write it in rows, columns would be defined later

Comment: `for i in range(len(b)):
    sheet.write(i,0,b[i])`
This will write on row[i], 0th column and b[i]. Is this you want?

Comment: @sk11 this would be partly what I want. The words should write both the worksheets. So the a list would be generated when i iterate over a code and every list should be written to different worksheets is what i want

Comment: Ok, now what are you unable to do? Post the error messages you are getting?

Comment: I am unable to write the code to do what i want to. I am not getting an errors. I am unable to write the code. so I'll have multiple lists like a to be be written to different worksheets from b

Comment: @sk11 I'll tell you the situation. I am working on a text search project and need to create worksheets for the company names and iterate over the text to write rows in different worksheets for the companies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said create 2 different worksheets with items in b, but you use items in a in your code. Why?
And try not to use same name when using for loop.
With this code, you can get a xls with two sheets, named 'company1' and 'company2'. In each sheet, from row 0 to row 2, there will be value defined in a.
Last but not least, don't forget to save.
Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import xlwt

base = xlwt.Workbook()

b = ['company1','company2']
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for name in b:
    n = 0
    s = base.add_sheet(name);
    for v in a:
        s.write(n, 0, v)
        n += 1

base.save('C:\\test.xls')
```

Comment: sorry, i forgot to change that. I'll tell you the situation. I am working on a text search project and need to create worksheets for the company names and iterate over the text to write rows in different worksheets for the companies. I am still trying to figure how to do that. if you run the above code, it doesn't work

Comment: Thanks Bud. I would really appreciate if you could advise on the below. I have a list of companies and few keywords. I need to form combinations of both the lists and google search and pull out the text from the html sites(which i have done already). Now I need to write excel files with the text from the sites using the keywords. So i'll have 3 lists: 1st(companies) 2nd(keywords) 3rd(list of text). Now i want to create worksheets with the 1st list and write out the text from the 3rd list in different worksheets from the competitors. I am getting confused

Comment: @RaghavShaligram  Replace a with 3rd list in the code. If you are not able to finish writing excel in 'for' loop, you can just write them in order. Try to add sheets one by one.